# How to edit an existing server that I created with node.js without creating a new server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch, puppeteer

I have a function in node.js which takes data with puppeteer and output it to a json file. The data that I take changes so I need my function to reset every so often and I do that with setInterval. Inside my function I have a

```
    var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
      if (req.url === "/"){
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000"})
        res.end(JSON.stringify(dataExplained))
      }
    })
    server.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1")
```

(dataExplained is the object which I store data in).
When it runs the second time in setInterval it outputs this error:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8080 
I understand why I get this error which is because I am creating and listening to a server on a port that exists but I don't know how to stop it.
Is there an editServer instead of create server or do I have to do something else?
***Please help***

Comment: It’s not `createServer`, it’s `server.listen` double call causes issue. So endpoint is already opened. Provide more details, it’s not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Define `dataExplained` **outside** your update function.

Update `dataExplained` from inside your update function.

Run your server once, when the script starts. Don't try creating a new server every time the value of `dataExplained` changes.

```
let dataExplained = { example: 1 };

const update => () => {
    dataExplained = { example: dataExplained.example + 1 };
}

setInterval(update, 2000);

const server = http.createServer( ... );
server.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```